# Merging single video track and multiple audio tracks on Android

Tags: android, audio, video, mp4parser

## The idea

I am creating a save to device feature for a movie editing application that merges one video track with one (or optionally two) audio tracks.

First, there are multiple video clips that I merge into **one single video track** using MP4Parser ([link](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)).

Then, there are multiple audio clips that I would like to merge into **one single audio track**. These clips should not be appended, but merged into a single audio track at specific times. E.g. we have two audio clips (A1, A2) and a 60 sec video track (V1). These audio clips can be overlapping, or having white noise inbetween them. The length of the whole audio track has to match the Video track, that can be up to 60 seconds. **There can be up to 100 audio clips added to the audio track 1**

- V1 - 60.0 s
- A1 - 0.3 s
- A2 - 1.1 s

Last, there might be an optional second audio track that contains a soundtrack as well, fit to the V1 video track.

## Summary

This is how it would look like:

Video track 1: [--------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 60 sec

Audio track 1: [-A1--A2--------------------------------------------------------------------] 60 sec

Audio track 2: [-------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 60 sec

## The problem

I tried approaching the problem by appending x second of white noise (empty wav file) to the audio track to get a full length track as described above, but that obviously would not work if the sounds are overlapping. What other ways can I try to tackle this problem?

```
private static final String OUTPUT = "output.mp4";
private static final String STORED_LOCATION = "/storage/emulated/0/"

/**
 * Merges two videos that are located in /storage/emulated/0/ and saves it to the same place with the given parameters. Uses the ffmpeg/javacv library. All this is done in an Async task, not blocking the UI thread but showing a progress bar and a toast at the end.
 *
 */
private void mergeVideosAsync()
{
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            try
            {
                List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mVideoPathList.size(); ++i)
                {
                    movieList.add(MovieCreator.build(new File(mVideoPathList.get(i)).getAbsolutePath()));
                }

                List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<>();
                List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<>();

                for (Movie m : movieList)
                {
                    for (Track t : m.getTracks())
                    {
                        if (t.getHandler().equals("soun"))
                        {
                            //TODO: Add audio tracks here to the merging process
                            // audioTracks.add(t);
                        }
                        if (t.getHandler().equals("vide"))
                        {
                            videoTracks.add(t);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Movie result = new Movie();
                if (audioTracks.size() > 0)
                {
                    result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
                }
                if (videoTracks.size() > 0)
                {
                    result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
                }
                BasicContainer out =  (BasicContainer) new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
                mOutputPath = String.format(STORED_LOCATION + File.separator + OUTPUT_FILENAME);
                WritableByteChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(mOutputPath, "rw").getChannel();
                out.writeContainer(fc);
                fc.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mOutputPath;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: were you able to solve this problem ? if so can you tell us how ?

Answer (score 0):

If your audio tracks are overlapping then you have a problem as you'll need reencode the audio.
If the audio tracks are non-overlapping then you might be able to use the SilenceTrackImpl:

```
 Track nuAudio = new AppendTrack(
    audioTrackA1, new SilenceTrackImpl(100), 
    audioTrackA2, new SilenceTrackImpl(500),        
    audioTrackA3, new SilenceTrackImpl(1000),
    audioTrackA4, new SilenceTrackImpl(50),
 )
```

and so on.